# How to add a group of values as a list?

Tags: list, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Please assume `#headerNames#` has the value of `Apple Orange Pear`.

How do I make this be considered as a list?

I tried this:

```
<cfset headerList = "">
<cfset headerList = ListAppend(headerList,"#headerNames#",",")>
```

But this doesn't work. So how do I store the values of `#headerNames#`as a list?

PS: the reason why I asked to assume `#headerNames#` is because the values come from reading an excel file, thus, a lot of unrelated codes to this question. But if those are needed, please let me know and I will edit / update the question.

Comment: The original value of headerNames is a space delimited list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually have to change anything for this to be considered a list. ColdFusion recognizes a `space` as a valid delimiter:

```
<cfset headerNames = "Apple Orange Pear">

<cfoutput>
    <cfloop list="#headerNames#" delimiters=" " index="i">
        #i#<br />
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>

<!--- output:
Apple
Orange
Pear
--->
```

Comment: This only gives me the output of 1 value.

Comment: No, [it works perfectly](http://trycf.com/gist/de72d20d350988284da4c7c7b90b5115/acf2016?theme=monokai). If it is not working for you, that means `headerNames` contains something different than you described. Do not rely on visual identification. Instead dump the `asc` value of each character in the string. Most likely what you are thinking is a space, is actually a different white space character. Hence, why it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ColdFusion `ListChangeDelims()` function to convert the `space` separated list to a comma separated list and then append the list to the required list. Like this

```
<cfscript>
  headerNames = "Apple Orange Pear";
  headerList = ListChangeDelims(headerNames,",", " ");
  writeoutput(headerList);
</cfscript>
```

The other solution I can think of is to use ColdFusion `ReReplace()` function to replace all spaces in the space separated list with `comma (,)`. Like this

```
<cfscript>
   headerNames = "Apple Orange Pear";
   headerList = ReReplace(headerNames," ", ",", "all");
   writeoutput(headerList);
</cfscript>
```

To read more about these functions, visit these links in the documentation:
[ListChangeDelims()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d6d.html) and [ReReplace()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e98.html).

Comment: Hi, I tried this but its not working. Basically the `#headerNames#` already contains a list with spaces, but I don't think its a list as I can't do a `listlen` on it. It will give a result of `1 1 1` if i do a listlen.

Comment: Not working how? To CF, a "list" is just a string delimited by some character - in this case it is a space. So yes, it is a "list".  I suspect listLen is not working because you forgot to set the delimiter to a space (defaults to a comma).

Answer (score 0):

Lists in ColdFusion are just strings so no conversion or casting is necessary and any string can be treated as a list.  Your headerNames field is already a list.

All list functions in ColdFusion have an optional delimiters field 
ie:

```
<cfset headerNamesLen = listlen(headerNames, " ")>              <!--- 3 --->
<cfset headerNames = listAppend(headerNames, "kiwi", " ")>      <!--- Apple Orange Pear kiwi --->
<cfset orangeIndex = listfind(headerNames, "Orange", " ")>      <!--- 2 --->
```

If you are required to return a list which will be used by other functions expecting a default comma-delimited list then use

```
<cfset headerList = ListChangeDelims(headerNames, ","," ")>
```

Since you are loading from an excel file - **if you also need to process blank entries** - it would look like this

```
<cfset headerNamesLen = listlen(headerNames, " ", true)>              <!--- 3 --->
<cfset headerNames = listAppend(headerNames, "kiwi", " ")>      <!--- Apple Orange Pear kiwi --->
<cfset orangeIndex = listfind(headerNames, "Orange", " ", true)>      <!--- 2 --->
```

Utilizing a second optional field *includeEmptyValues*